# Is there a way to proxy api calls in production

Tags: api, vue.js, proxy, cors, production

I have a vue.js frontend and I need to make api calls to an external api which doesn't allow cross-origin.
Is there a way to proxy this in the vue frontend, in development I used a devServer proxy and this worked. I could always forward it through my own spring backend but this seems like a worse solution then just proxy in the fontend.

Comment: There's no way to do this on the frontend, you'll need to have some sort of server that proxies the requests. The easiest way would be to just create a basic proxy with NGINX.

Comment: `proxy in the fontend` ...such thing does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in production, proxy through bachend server seems right solution for you.
Also you can do a lot of stuff, like caching answers from external api, working with data immediately, without additional frontend work. Just try to do it.

If i were you, i'd just create/add separate service on backend that should work with that api.